# Permission issue with dumped android (and encrypted) /data partition

Tags: permissions, encryption, android

Recently I had a issue with my phone and I wiped it, but before I dumped (

```bsh
adb pull /dev/block/sda29
```

) all the /data partition that was on my phone.
After that I mounted the image simply with

```bsh
sudo mount ./sda29 /mnt/data/
```

the file mounted normally but now I'm not able to browse inside /mnt/data/media/0 folder: it give me an error when trying to list files (even with root shell):

```
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

I think is caused by android internal storage encryption, but then how can I decrypt/access those files?
(My phone is a Xiaomi Mi 9 SE, with android 9 installed)

Thank you very much.

Comment: `/data/media` is owned by UID/GID `1023` with mode `0770`. So you won't be able to traverse it with any other UID (except root). Secondly if you are able to mount it it's definitely not FDE encrypted. But possibly there is FBE. See if filenames are encrypted, and if so, you are most probably out of luck due to hardware-backed encryption used on Android: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215445/218526

Comment: oh, ok I see... what if I reinstall everything I set the old password for encryption an I reflash the data partition on device, maybe then I'm able to decrypt it? I read in another forum rolling back to older kernels (which I did flashing an old backup) the encryption may break. So I was wandering what if I put on my phone the latest kernel and the /data dump I have?

Comment: The problematic part is not mainly the kernel, but [**hardware-backed encryption**](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk#storing_the_encrypted_key). See the link given in previous comment and this one for more details: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216410/218526. While reading do focus on that you have **wiped** your phone.